# How is Windows Authentication Wired Up?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-authentication, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm in the process of creating an ASPNET Core 6 MVC app in VS 2022 which will eventually be deployed in a Docker container. Windows Authentication will be used as it's an internal app. When creating this project from scratch with File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Core 6 Web App (Model-View-Controller) and with Windows Authentication enabled, everything works as expected.

This is where it gets weird. Since this will be a Docker container on Linux, I commented out the IIS settings in launchSettings.json.

```
{
  //"iisSettings": {
  //  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  //  "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  //  "iisExpress": {
  //    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60583",
  //    "sslPort": 44391
  //  }
  //},
  "profiles": {
    "ASPNETCORE6": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7276;http://localhost:5276",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To recreate this issue, comment out the following from the generated Program.cs file:

```
    //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
    
    //builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    //   .AddNegotiate();

    //builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    //{
    //  options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    //});
    
    //app.UseAuthentication();
    //app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now, when I run a debugging session using IIS Express, the browser windows renders **with my correct domain name being displayed**. How is this even possible? Is something being cached? Also, the browser is going to http://localhost:44391/ when debugging with IIS Express even though this is commented out in launchSettings.json.

**Note:** Windows authentication is not working when I debug with Kestrel, which is what I would expect.

Comment: "IIS Integration Middleware is configured to automatically authenticate requests by default....The ASP.NET Core Module is configured to forward the Windows Authentication token to the app by default.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio  Also consider how your web.config.xml is set.

Comment: @pcalkins, I'm not using IIS.

Comment: that should apply to Kestrel too...

Comment: @pcalkins your explanation is the only one that makes sense. Feel free to post it as an answer.